# Wait for GetComponent() to load

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When calling GetComponent() just after my program starts up, I find that the method sometimes does not return a component quickly enough to prevent a null reference exception when code later tries to access the component member variable. My question is - is there a way to wait for GetComponent to finish finding what it needs to? I know can wait using coroutines, but is there another way to do this with some kind of lambda callback or event?

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool AutosaveEnabled = true;
    public static GameManager Instance;
    [HideInInspector] public InputManager InputManager;
    [HideInInspector] public UIManager UIManager;
...

    private void Awake()
    {
        Setup();
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
    else
    { 
         throw new Exception();
    }

        UIManager = GetComponent<UIManager>();
...
        UIManager.Setup();
...
}


public class UIManager : StateMachine, IUIManager
{
    public static UIManager Instance;
    public ITitleMenu TitleMenu;    

    public void Setup()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
    else
    { 
         throw new Exception();
    }

        TitleMenu = GetComponentInChildren<ITitleMenu>();

    }


    private void SetupScene()
    {
       UIManager.Instance.ChangeState<TitleMenuState>();
    }
...
}

public interface ITitleMenu : IMenu
{
    void ExitGame();
    void LoadTitleMenuScene();    
    void OnNewGameClick();
}

public interface IMenu
{
    public void Setup(IUIManager uiManager);
    public void SetActive(bool toggle);
    int selectedIndex { get; set; }
    int previouslySelectedIndex { get; set; }
    TextMeshProUGUI[] Options { get; set; }
    void OnControllerMoveDown();
    void OnControllerMoveUp();
    void OnControllerConfirm();
}


public class TitleMenu : MenuBase, ITitleMenu
{
    private enum MenuElements { Continue, NewGame, Controls, VideoSettings, AudioSettings, ExitGame };

    public void Setup(IUIManager uiManager)
    {
        this.uiManager = uiManager;
        DataManager.Instance.SaveFileMetadata = GameManager.Instance.SaveFileManager.GetSaveFileMetadata();
        if (DataManager.Instance.SaveFileMetadata.Count > 0)
        {
            Options[(int)MenuElements.Continue].transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            selectedIndex = (int)MenuElements.Continue;
        }
        else
        {
            Options[(int)MenuElements.Continue].transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            selectedIndex = (int)MenuElements.NewGame;
        }

        previouslySelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
    }
...
}

public class StateMachine : MonoBehaviour, IStateMachine
{
    public virtual State CurrentState
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentState;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentState == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_currentState != null)
            {
                _currentState.Exit();
            }

            _currentState = value;

            if (_currentState != null)
            {
                _currentState.Enter();
            }
        }
    }
    protected State _currentState;

    public virtual T GetState<T>() where T : State
    {
        T target = GetComponent<T>();
        if (target == null)
        {
            target = gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
            target.Initialize();
        }
        return target;
    }
}
...


public class TitleMenuState : UIState
{
    protected override void OnMove(object sender, InfoEventArgs<Vector2> e)
    {
        if (e.info.y == 1)
        {
            owner.TitleMenu.OnControllerMoveUp();
        }
        else if (e.info.y == -1)
        {
            owner.TitleMenu.OnControllerMoveDown();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInteract(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        owner.TitleMenu.OnControllerConfirm();
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {
        owner.TitleMenu.SetActive(true);
        owner.TitleMenu.Setup(owner);
        EventManager.UIMoveEvent += OnMove;
        EventManager.UISubmitEvent += OnInteract;
    }

    public override void Exit()
    {
        UIManager.Instance.TitleMenu.SetActive(false);
        EventManager.UIMoveEvent -= OnMove;
        EventManager.UISubmitEvent -= OnInteract;
    }
}

public abstract class State : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void Enter()
    {
    }

    public virtual void Exit()
    {
    }

    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
    }

}


public abstract class UIState : State
{
    protected UIManager owner;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        owner = UIManager.Instance;
    }

    protected virtual void OnInteract(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected virtual void OnCancel(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {
    }

    public override void Exit()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void OnMove(object sender, InfoEventArgs<Vector2> e)
    {

    }

    public virtual bool IsStateOfType(UIStates state)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Right now the game crashes in TitleMenuState.Enter() where I'm calling owner.TitleMenu.SetActive() because TitleMenu is null.

Hierarchy:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include enough information to reproduce the problem described. Questions should include a [mre]. For Unity this means enough code, hierarchy, and inspector configuration to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not respectful of the time of people willing to help to ask them to go and find these cases. If you already know of these relevant cases, please include them in the question.

Comment: `GetComponent()` is not async .. it is a blocking call and if the component exists it will be returned ...

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me. `GetComponent` returns a component. Until it is able to return one, it doesn't return. It certainly never returns null and then returns something later... I don't know how that could even work in c#. What am I missing?

Comment: For starters - where are you running `GetComponent`? Where is the "other code" running? If the "other code" is running in the main thread (which means it's simply being called *before* `GetComponent` is even started), then Omi's answer will likely be enough. But from how the question suggests things are happening simultaneously... if the "other code" is running in a non-main thread... then other methods of synchronizing may be necessary. More details are needed

Comment: Unity doesn't allow a portion of its API to be used by threads other than the main thread. GetComponent is one of the methods that will outright crash if it is used on anything other than the main thread. It's also synchronous, returning the component immediately (or null, if such a component isn't on the gameobject).

Comment: @LukeBriggs, ok, that's interesting

Comment: Nothing in the code above calls `UIManager.Setup` so presumably owner.TitleMenu will always be null if the code is ran as-is

Comment: Your code is missing too many things to be able to help out, but the premise of your question is definitely wrong - GetComponent always completes syncronously and does not require waiting for; the issue is you're basically not calling it, or its return value was null because the thing you tried to obtain is not actually in the hierarchy at that point in time.

Comment: It should be a minimal reproducible example, meaning the code runs and reproduces the issue. If you try to copy the above code into Unity, you'll get a syntax error, followed by 24 errors.

Comment: Looks like the TitleMenu gameobject isn't active, so GetComponentInChildren won't find components inside of it. I don't know how we were supposed to know that TitleMenu isn't active without asking you (repeatedly) for that information.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because there is now enough info to suggest using `GetComponentsInChildren<ITitleMenu>(true)[0];` would probably work. And, yes, now the question is a lot better now for having more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time `TitleMenu = GetComponentInChildren<ITitleMenu>();` is run in the `UIManager` component of the `GameManager` gameobject, the child gameobject `TitleMenu` is inactive, and that child is what has the `ITitleMenu` on it. And, from [the documentation on `GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) (emphasis mine):

> Returns the component of Type type in the GameObject or any of its children using depth first search.
>
> ***A component is returned only if it is found on an active GameObject.***

So that will return `null`. This has nothing to do with failing to return "quickly enough".

A very simple workaround is to use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html), which has an optional `includeInactive` parameter that will allow for searching inactive objects. Using `GetComponentsInChildren`, with `includeInactive` as true should have the desired result, only needing to index the first element (since it returns an array):

```
public class UIManager : StateMachine, IUIManager
{
    public static UIManager Instance;
    public ITitleMenu TitleMenu;    

    public void Setup()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
    else
    { 
         throw new Exception();
    }

    TitleMenu = GetComponentsInChildren<ITitleMenu>(true)[0];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call GetComponent() before using the component. You could also check out Script Execution order menu (Edit - Project Settings - Script Execution order)

Comment: Doesn't matter where you call the `GetComponent` as it will return the component as long as its attached to the `GameObject` in question.  Race conditions have nothing to do with this.

Comment: There were no code or pictures when I left answer. Also, it does matter. Try using component in Awake() but calling it in Start().

Comment: That is just how references work in C# it has nothing to do with `GetComponent`. If you use **lazy-init property** to refer to the component you can call it in `Start` and `Awake` and it'll always return the component if said component is attached to the `GameObject`.

Comment: Script execution order should be used in rare cases where you have a script that is used by many other scripts but needs to initialize first. But even for this there are better patterns out there like having root script of sorts that makes sure all scenes are loaded and then handles the initialization of components in controlled order with logic spread to multiple frames with co-routines to avoid long loading screen freezes (overkill for simple games but must for larger games).